# How to put Java source inside IDE

Tags: java, ide

I have a Java program source files, complete with its subdirectories. My problem is, how can I put all of this inside an IDE (ie. Netbeans, Eclipse) , so that I can easily, modify, compile and package it to become a *.jar file.

Comment: you can create a new project and link this folder to that project in eclipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Eclipse:** File->New->Java Project, then check "Create project from existing source" instead of "Create new project in workspace"

**Netbeans** has similar way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using Maven as your build tool there are some nice plugins for creating a project file that you can open in your IDE.

For example:

Eclipse: `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Intellij IDA: `mvn idea:idea`

Comment: Or you can simply use "import the project from an external model" in IDEA or install m2eclipse in Eclipse and use it to import the project. The path is similar for ant based builds...